# Model data not being sent to controllers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 project; specifically I'm working on CodePlex Music Store example (which can be found here https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/).
However, I created a controller with views for an entity (Album) and when I try to run the edit operation, this exception is thrown when it tries to save changes to the database (while everything works fine for the other operations such as delete and create):

> **Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded.**

I added a breakpoint on saving changes, and it turns out some of the model data (including `AlbumId`) are not sent; some of them is sent and others are null. I'm sure that `AlbumId` is included in the view as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Album</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlbumId)...
```

And here is the action in the controller that handles the request

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        return View(album);
    }
```

How can I send it or find out why it is not being sent?

Comment: Show part of your view and controller related to this issue

Comment: Is your HiddenFor inside @Html.Form?

Comment: Chances are something is not persisting when you load the album into the editing form.  Can you post the entire edit controller method?

Comment: I edited the post and added the controller method and a part of the view where I include the AlbumId property.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be modified like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // entity is attached to the context, so that it is tracked and its changes saved
        db.Attach(album);
        db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
    ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
    return View(album);
}
```

If you have unfilled properties in your `album`, one way to check your submitted data is to add a [FormCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.118).aspx) parameter to your method. This parameter will be automatically filled with form data and you can check your exact key names and their values. Also, you must pay attention to what you have `Include`d with that `Bind` attribute, as all other submitted form data will be wiped out.

Comment: Thanks, I used the FormCollection parameter and realized that the form was entirely submitted, but still I can't find the sent data in `AlbumId` parameter.

Comment: Can you also include value for key AlbumId from FormCollection and your Album class definition?